# How can i give style to a h3 tag used in js code when that h3 shows onclick for a button?

Tags: javascript, css

i created a button in my HTML file and i want to make it when some one click on that button, it clear the HTML tags and show a text.
i can do that, i use

```
onclick="document.write(<h3>'***'</h3>)"
```

but my problem is i cant give style with CSS to the h3 when it shows.

i tried to give it style with CSS my code is look like this:

```
<style>
   button h3 {
     color:red;
   }
</style>
```

but it didn't worked :(

Comment: Is your `h3` element a child of the `button` element? That is to say, is your syntax something like this: `<button><h3>some text</h3></button>`? If it's not, then your CSS syntax is incorrect - you should only be targeting the `h3`, and the way it's currently setup, you're saying something along the lines of: *I want to set the colour of every h3 which is inside a button to red*

Comment: When you use `document.write` to add new content to the page, it's being added directly to the HTML without any of the associated CSS styles. Therefore, you won't be able to style the new content using CSS selectors.

Comment: @TermoPollo
so how i can give styles to the new document that `document.write` created?

Comment: @FiddlingAway  you're right, my syntax is wrong, but can you tell me what is the right way to do what i want please?
sorry i'm new in coding :)

Comment: Instead of using `document.write`, you should use **JavaScript DOM manipulation methods** such as `innerHTML`, `appendChild`, `createElement`, etc. These methods modify the existing DOM and allow you to add new elements to the page while still maintaining the association with your CSS styles.

Comment: If you want to influence the colour of `h3`, and only `h3`, you just need to do: `h3  { color:red; }` . Now, regarding the `onclick` - I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to replace every `h3` text with asterisks / * characters, you can use a combination of `document.getElementsByTagName` and `innerHTML = "***"`. Is that what you are trying to do?